# Advanced file upload validation in CakePHP 2.6

Tags: validation, cakephp

I've got a system for uploading .KML and .KMZ files in my CakePHP 2.6 app, and am running up against an issue with validation.

Normally, if you want to limit file uploads to certain filetypes, you'd put something like the following in your model:

```
public $validate = array(
    'file_upload' => array(
        'extension' => array(
            'rule' => array('extension', array('kml', 'kmz')),
             'message' => 'Only KML or KMZ files',
         ),
    )
);
```

However, this kind of checking doesn't test if the file is corrupted, or if there were other issues.

I'm using a function called from `beforeSave()` which processes the file specified in `$this->data['UploadModel']['upload_file']['tmp_name']`, unzipping to a temp folder if it's a .KMZ, then converting to an XML document, iterating over nodes, and converting node data to child records we need to save. At each step in the process, something could go wrong: The ZIP could be malformed, the XML could be malformed, there might not be any useful data in the XML.

What's the "right" way to do advanced file validation like this? I could put some of this logic into a custom validator function, but then I'd have to duplicate a lot of code, unzip files twice, et cetera.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think validation (and validation messages) is the right tool for *data processing*. The whole code should be already reside in a model. Each of the steps should be a separate method as well. You can use the `RuntimeException` or other, depending on the case, better matching exceptions.

In your controller / shell that does the processing you can catch it and flash the error message:

```
try {
    $this->Model->processUploadedKmlFile($this->request->data);
} catch (\Execption $e) {
    $this->Session->setFlash($e->getMessage());
    // Redirect or do something else
}
```